# Laravel 6 redis caching not able to get cached items

Tags: caching, redis, laravel-6, homestead

[Update]

I find that laravel cashes in only 1 key no matter how many keys I try to save but I always find only 1 key this one "laravel:9a261d789b8265a6b0495ea5d87481b4589422b1"

I have tried

```
if (Cache::store('redis')->has('bar')) {
    echo ' - bar key cache exists - ';
}
else{
    echo  ' - bar key cache does not exist - ';
}
Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 600);
$value = Cache::get('bar');
echo $value; exit;
```

And I always get  `- bar key cache does not exist - baz` why!!??

---

I'm trying to implement redis caching in Laravel Homestead localhost here's the .env

```
PP_NAME=mysite
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:887AJ9PHxl7W/QS4g8VrMch6CTL4QMLneq4dHx2KhoE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://mysite.test:44300
PAGINATE=10
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

and config/database.php

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],
],
```

in config/cache.php

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
    ],
```

Now in the controller:

```
$posts = Cache::remember('posts_cache', 600, function () use ($where) {
        return Post::where($where)->inRandomOrder()->paginate(3);
    });
```

when I print `$posts` every time I get different posts not the cached 3 posts. I run

```
redis-cli monitor
```

And find that it's caching. I run

```
redis-cli
```

Then

```
keys *
```

I get this

```
1) "laravel:9a261d789b8265a6b0495ea5d87481b4589422b1"
2) "laravel:9a261d789b8265a6b0495ea5d87481b4589422b1:timer"
```

How can I retrieve cached data from redis? what's wrong with my code?

Comment: what does it print when you run `redis-cli monitor` in background and invoke your controller method ? Something like `setex`, `get` ? The keys you shared looks like session keys (one is for session the other one is for rate limiter) so it doesn't cache your posts or `bar`.

Comment: Yes I get ````setex```` and ````get````

Comment: 1600611360.560727 [0 127.0.0.1:36166] "GET" "laravel:books_category_home_random"
1600611360.641378 [0 127.0.0.1:36166] "SETEX" "laravel:books_category_home_random" ......